# Подскажите пожалуйста, как обрезать текстовую строку в PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Необходимо столбец а, пример: ['environment', 'math'] ['649.091', '778.909']
обрезать до следующей квадратной скобки, т.е. основная задача такой столбец разбить на два, в первом - первые квадратные скобки, во втором соответственно вторые

Comment: каким запросом получен пример?

Comment: ::json ->> 'Столбец'::text из массива

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
select 
  (regexp_matches(theTextToSplit, '^(\[[^\[\]]+\]) *(\[[^\[\]]+\])'))[1],
  (regexp_matches(theTextToSplit, '^(\[[^\[\]]+\]) *(\[[^\[\]]+\])'))[2]
 from ...
```

Если надо - можно оптимизировать с `CTE` или `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`.

Comment: огромное вам спасибо!